# How can I replace $('form') with something Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to send some forms data, using AngularJS HTTP POST in Json format so It can be portable from NodeJS and MongoDB to and from Apache MySQL PHP.

So I think that Json is the common ground for all that.

I noticed that if we post raw Json data to PHP we could not use the *$_POST* variables.

We have to use ;

`$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");`

And refer to the data like this

```
$jsonData = json_decode($postData);
$jsonData->someValueName
```

My HTTP request in Angular is sending information in the json format.

Ex in plain text;

```
{username:"Charlie", password:"Delta"}
```

These values comes from an Angular Model and are sent using $http

```
 $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajax-processor.php',       // could be Node as well
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'Content-Type: application/json'},
        data:  { username: $scope.username, password:$scope.password}      
    }).then(function successCallback(response) { 
// deal with response 
}
```

I dont wank to make several functions to send all kind of diffrents forms. Username and password are just the basic.

I have been looking for a way to pass all the form at once to my request.
I dont want to use Jquery for this. even if I really like the fact that I could acheive that.

Ex;

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax-processor.php', 
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},      
            data:  $('form').serializeArray()      <-----CHANGED 
        }).then(function successCallback(response) { 
    // deal with response 
    }
```

Now in this case *serializeArray()* outputs urlencode;

```
username=Charlie&password=Delta&etc=...
```

And serialize() outputs an object;

```
[{ 
  0: {name: "username", value: "Charlie"}
  1: {name: "password", value: "Delta"}
}]
```

So how can I replace $('form') with something Angular.

Comment: The output of serializeArray is an array, the items within the array are objects, so you won't be able to use json_decode

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of `serializeArray`. This produces the following data structure: `{
    name: "a",
    value: "1"
  }`

Comment: Yes i am receiving an array. i have tried adding the content type and its the same result. However if I echo $postdata i get everything in [{ data:data, dat.....}] if If I echo $postdata[0] i get the fist charachter of the string [

Answer (score 1):

If you want an object and not an array, you should use `jQuery.serialize()` instead of `jQuery.serializeArray()`.

This will create a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    username: "The Master User",
    password: "password",
    ajaxKey: "Mykey"
}
```

Is there a specific reason why you use the stdin? This is a major overkill, you can simply use the superglobal `$_POST`, which is an associative array:

```
if($_POST['ajaxKey'] == "Mykey"){
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: if i use serialize()  im getting username=The%20Master%20User&password=password&ajaxKey=Mykey

I use $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

And if i try to read $_POST['ajaxKey'] im not getting anything

Comment: Strange. Can you try the `$http.post()` method? Because I think `$http()` itself does not send a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` HTTP header...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that cuse as it is im using the http post method with AngularJS

Comment: With this method you cant get post as they are not populated so i use $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

Comment: That's what I mean. This is not how it should be done. The data should be in the POST data, not the POST body. You should not need to use `php://input`... So my guess is that angularJS `$http` class doesn't send a header. Or maybe it's because you wrote `method: 'post'` lowercase instead of uppercase... It would be interesting to see if the `$http` service shortcut function for POST would fix this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: dang let me see il try it

Comment: But then. when I refer to Json data it is causing an error.  After testing I realized that I have to use $_POST for urlencoded data but it is not possible to pass json data to a $_POST It will cause an error. And i like Json for API and Mongo. So what are the pros and cons about using Json rather then URLEcode? In both way it remains a POST

Comment: So after all that I rewrote the question cuse i want to keep it to Json